# SqlAlchemy flask cascade save json

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the follow class:

```
class Identity(Base):
"Identity model."

__tablename__ = 'identity'

id = Column('ID_IDENTITY', Integer, Sequence('identity_seq'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
uuid = Column('DS_UUID', String(32), ForeignKey('customer.NX_UUID'), nullable=False)
type = Column('DS_TYPE', String(255), nullable=False)
value = Column('DS_VALUE', String(255), nullable=False)
```

and

```
class Customer(Base):
"Customer model."

__tablename__ = 'customer'

uuid = Column('NX_UUID', String(32), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
name = Column('DS_NICK_NAME', String(255), nullable=False)

identities = relationship(Identity, backref=backref('custome', cascade='all', uselist=True), lazy='dynamic')
```

I want to post a new customer passing a list of indentities, i trying to do this with follow json:

```
{"name":"Teste", uuid: "12121212121","identities":[{"type":"cpf","value":"05882110955"}, {"CNPJ":"0123456656"}, {"RG":"AAA3243"}]}
```

but I get the error:

```
 unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Any ideias to do this?

tks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the identities SQLAlchemy model objects, like this:

```
cust = Customer(name="Test", uuid="12121212121")
id1 = Identity(type="cpf", value="05882110955", uuid="asdasda")
id2 = Identity(type="CNPJ", value="0123456656", uuid="sdzxc3")

cust.identites = [id1, id2]
db_session.add(cust)
db_session.commit()
```

Comment: i'm doing this, but I want to map my json in a python object to save, in a same operation. Like this:

    cust = Customer (**json_data)
    db_session.add(cust)
    db_session.commit()

Comment: Need to do the same for the Identity objects in the dict too.

Comment: Yeah, but I dont want to do separete, I need a solution that I pass any json (with relationships) and convert to object (like a custumer). If I have more then a relationship, I need just pass this json.